# python - how to pass slack token to python app from dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have my python app, in which i am passing my slack tokens via json file.

so my **config.json** is :

```
{
  "slack_bot_token":"xoxb-12345789",
  "slack_signing_secret":"AAA23245GJ"
}
```

So my **slackeventsapp.py** is :

```
 from slackeventsapi import SlackEventAdapter
    from slackclient import SlackClient
    import json

    tokens = {}
    with open('config.json') as json_data:
        tokens = json.load(json_data)

    EVENT_ADAPTER = SlackEventAdapter(tokens.get("slack_signing_secret"), "/slack/events")
    SLACK_CLIENT = SlackClient(tokens.get("slack_bot_token"))

    def PostMsg(channel, text):
        SLACK_CLIENT.api_call("chat.postMessage", channel=channel, text=text)
```

so I need to pass the two values **slack_signing_secret** and **slack_bot_token** via dockerfile. Please help how cna we pass this.

Comment: If you do, _anyone_ who has your image can `docker run ... cat config.json` and get your credentials out.  Do not put any sort of credentials in your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: then how to pass @DavidMaze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copy the config file using your Dockerfile. This way the config file will be in the built image.
2. Mount a volume where the config file is kept.

There might be other ways.